# How to get a full backup of a hard disk from a dead MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup

My MacBook is not booting up due to some short circuit problem.

Apple Store has promised that they can repair but there would be data loss.

I want to take out the hard disk from the MacBook and take a backup of it. Then re-attach the hard disk and give my MacBook for repairing!

So far I am unable to find any way to do a full backup of a hard drive.

I would like to get some helpful pointers.

Comment: Find a takeapart guide on [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Mac_Laptop) - you didn't give your machine model - then get the drive into an external USB enclosure & recover to another machine.

Comment: Model : Mac book pro ...

Comment: But how to recover to another machine ?

Comment: @sathishkumar_kingmaker, Please provide the full model info e.g.: "MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013"

Comment: MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013 only  I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your MacBook model, removing the hard drive may void your warranty, so it might be better to prediscuss this with the store or ask them for other options. They may also offer you a way that they can do the backup for you (at extra cost maybe) or give you the old hard disk back after getting your MacBook working again.

Comment: Is it possible that we can take out the hard-drive and connect it using usb cable to copy and paste it some where so we can later put back ?

Comment: You are going to need an external HD enclosure for this.

Comment: That's ok..can you give me the steps please

Comment: IFixit.com has a lot of instructions for the individual MacBook models out there.

Comment: After thorough diagnosis,finally the porblem turned out to be battery problem ! Now its fixed and its working ! :)